# What could be the equation of this curve?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Does anyone have an idea what (parametric) equation might give a plot like this?

[image]

This is in the XY plane. I want to render it nicely on Mathematica, hence why I need the equation.

So far I came up with $\{t*\sin[t/2], \cos[t/2]\}$ which seems to be on the right track but doesn't quite do what I want...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ParametricPlot[(1 + .1 Sin[θ/2 - π/4]) {Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 4 π}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need perfect circles, maybe:
[image: Figure2]
[image: Figure2]